# How can I get the position of specific term produced by Lucene(5.3)

Tags: java, lucene, information-retrieval

I am trying to get inverted index by Lucene5.3.0. When I try to get the position of specific term position with the code below, I find that **dpe(DocsAndPositionsEnum) is null**. Below is the implementation.

> Implementation in function createIndex:

```
FieldType myFieldType = new FieldType(TextField.TYPE_STORED);
myFieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);
myFieldType.storeTermVectorPositions();
document.add(new Field("contents", content, myFieldType));
```

> Snippet in function showIndex:

```
Document doc = reader.document(docNum);
System.out.println("Processing file:"+doc.get("filename"));

Terms termVector = reader.getTermVector(docNum, "contents");
System.out.println("termVector is null?"+String.valueOf(termVector==null));
TermsEnum itr = termVector.iterator();
BytesRef term = null;

while((term = itr.next()) != null){
    try{
        DocsAndPositionsEnum dpe = itr.docsAndPositions(null, null);
        System.out.println(dpe==null);
        int freq = -1;
        if (dpe != null) freq = dpe.freq();
        System.out.println(freq);
        for (int fi = 0; fi< freq; fi++){
            final int position = dpe.nextPosition();
            System.out.println("position: "+ String.valueOf(position));
        }

        String termText = term.utf8ToString();
        Term termInstance = new Term("contents",term);                      
        long termFreq = reader.totalTermFreq(termInstance);
        long docCount = reader.docFreq(termInstance);

        System.out.println("term: "+termText+", termFreq = "+termFreq+", docCount = "+docCount);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

}

May you help me with the problem? 
Great thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`storeTermVectorPositions` is the getter, you have to use `setStoreTermVectorPositions` in your `createIndex` function:

```
myFieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
```

Normally, you'd have to traverse the `DocsAndPositionsEnum` in two levels, first docs then positions, but since it's a term vector, there's only going to be one document. You still have to position the `DocsAndPositionsEnum` to get access to the positions and frequencies:

```
DocsAndPositionsEnum dpe = itr.docsAndPositions(null, null);
int docId = dpe.nextDoc();
assert docId == docNum;
int freq = dpe.freq();
```

Lastly, `DocsAndPositionsEnum` is a deprecated API, better to use `PostingsEnum` instead. The API is the same:

```
org.apache.lucene.index.PostingsEnum dpe = itr.postings(null);
dpe.nextDoc();
dpe.freq();
dpe.nextPosition();
```